# Rails app running too slow with nginx passenger on ec2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, passenger

I am running rails app using nginx and passenger on ec2-instance t2.small with 2GB RAM and 1 CPU Core.

App contains spree and related gems in development mode. Spree backend used to work fine but since last 3 days, it's taking too much time to respond and start up time is too high if remain idle for some time. I tried various combination of passenger methods in nginx but not helped so I omitted those and below is nginx file in current scenario

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.20;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/wrappers/ruby;
    passenger_app_env development;

    #added two lines for setting user group
    passenger_default_user root;
    passenger_default_group root;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    passenger_spawn_method smart;
    passenger_pool_idle_time 1000; 

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root /var/www/html/apps/localfiles/public;
        passenger_enabled on;


        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  abcd.com www.abcd.com;
    root /var/www/html/apps/abcd/ComingSoon;
    passenger_enabled on;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  xyz.com www.xyz.com;
        root /var/www/html/apps/xyz/ComingSoon;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
}
```

Any light on what should be the right combination for nginx / passenger configuration would be highly appreciated.

Update: When I use Spree APIs, I need to hit an API 3-4 times to get proper response, it's throwing me this `Web application could not be started` very often in between API calls. please help with this

Comment: I would check the whole app with an application monitoring tool like newrelic. Without some metrics it's hard to tell, if the machine overall is a little slow, there are to few nginx workers, passenger workers, db bottle neck. I'm not related to newrelic in any case, but I really recommend using it (free version available) at least while tuning the performance.

Comment: Hi @JulianKaffke , thanks for info I will certainly look at newrelic. But for now, what I am getting now is this very weird error `Web application could not be started` very often, can you help me with that?

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace / complete error page?

Answer (score 1):

**DB Connection**

In my experience, the DB Connection is the single biggest bottleneck for Rails apps.

I've found this mainly from Heroku, which [uses Amazon's EC cloud](https://www.heroku.com/policy/security#compliance) - external databases *seriously* slow down applications.

--

You've neither mentioned whether you're pulling from a DB, nor what DB setup you're using.

The further away (geographically) the db server is to your web server, the slower the application runs.

I remember hooking our dev MYSQL db into our production app, and waiting 3/5 seconds to refresh; having db server in same data center pushed that time down to 0.25s.

**I'd strongly recommend checking your production DB**

Amazon provides its own [MYSQL db functionality](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/), which I'd strongly recommend you use.

If you have budget, go with [RackSpace](http://rackspace.com) (they have MYSQL servers and web servers in the same data center) - Rails apps run blazingly fast with them.

Comment: Thanks @rich-peck for throwing some light, I am using _mysql_ db on the same instance with `gem 'mysql2'` , However, I am not sure db connection is causing this

Comment: I didn't think it would but I wanted to put it out there. Do you have a link to a repo or live app we could see?